# How to seed a model that has a relationship to itself

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

I am using Laravel 8 and PHP v7.4 I have a model with a schema generated with the below migration.

**CreateContestsTable**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('contests', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->foreignId('contest_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('contest_id')->references('id')->on('contests');
    });
}
```

A `contest` can have many `contests`. To seed this, I have generated a factory class.

**ContestFactory**

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->faker->paragraph(),
    ];
}
```

**ContestSeeder**

```php
public function run()
{
    \App\Models\Contest::factory(10)->create([
        'contest_id' => array_rand(\App\Models\Contest::all()->pluck('id')->toArray())
    ]);
}
```

The above throws the following error.

> ErrorException
> array_rand(): Array is empty

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: they haven't been created yet at that point ... you can call `create()->each(...)` to iterate through them after they are all created though

Comment: Thanks @lagbox If this was an answer I would have accepted it. `create()->each(...)` is what I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The records have not been created yet when you do the query to pluck the information. You can call `create()` with no arguments so it creates the records then you can iterate the returned Collection:

```
\App\Models\Contest::factory(10)->create()->each(...);
```